# Error in Hyperlink Shiny datatable

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I have this code that creates a hyperlink using a paste0 function.
But when clicked the URL reads:

http://127.0.0.1:4350/www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html

The http://127.0.0.1:4350/ is always before.
in the rest of the code in another section it works fine.

in the URL1 column the data is www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html
here is some code:

ui

```
(...)
 tabsetPanel(
                                                              tabPanel("Products", dataTableOutput("table1")),
(...)
```

server

```
(...)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

            output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({

                    search <- input$name
                    df <- subset(products, grepl(search, products$Name, ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE)
                    df$Model <- paste("<a href= '",df$URL1,"' target='_blank '>",df$Model,"</a>")
                    df2 <- subset(df, Clonality == input$clonality)
                    df3  <- df2[,tbl]
                    colnames(df3) <- c("Name", "Model", "Short Description", "Human Gene Symbol", "Sizes", "Price Pounds", "Price Dollars", "Price Euros", "Reviews" )
                    datatable(df3, escape = FALSE)%>%formatStyle("Reviews",backgroundColor=styleInterval(1.10, c("red", "green")))%>%formatStyle("Name","Price Dollars",backgroundColor=styleEqual("132 214.5 264", "orange"))


            })
(...)
```

Comment: What does your `df$Model` and `df$URL1` initially contain?

Comment: The df$Model is just a number, the df$URL1 contains the link to that product page.

Answer (score 0):

> the URL1 column the data is www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html

If you add a http:// infront of the url, it should work. The URLs in the column should read:

```
http://www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html
```

Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment your data looks something like this:

```
 Model                                       URL1
  1       www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html
  2       www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html
```

Here is a minimal example for your code to work:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(Model = c("1", "2"), URL1 = c("www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html", "www.companyname.com/test/test/product.html"))


ui <- fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output){

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    df$Model <- paste0("<a href= '","http://",df$URL1,"' target='_blank '>",df$Model,"</a>")
    DT::datatable(df, escape = FALSE)

    })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Your URL1 is missing `http://` which is causing the error. Also, instead of `paste` I have to used `paste0` so that there are no unnecessary spaces.

Hope it helps!